# NodeJS Plotly - how to wait for getImage to finish before continuing

Tags: javascript, node.js, plotly

So, what I am trying to accomplish is basically: Generating a plot by using NodeJS and plotly for NodeJS and getting it into my filesystem (with `getImage`), and proceeding with the image afterwards. My problem is, that the function returns before finishing and getting the image into my filesystem. So my result is basically that after I'm calling `generate_plot()`, the file does not exist yet and I'm getting an error. Now onto my question: How do I wait for `generate_plot()` to finish and to getting the image into my filesystem *before* continuing and using this image/to use this image?

```
const fs = require("fs");
var plotly = require('plotly')(username, api_key);

function generate_plot(){
    var trace = {
      type: 'bar',
      x: ['Mario', 'Luigi', 'Bowser'],
      y: [50000, 10000, 2000],
      marker: {color: ["red", "green", "darkblue"]},
    };

    var layout = {
      plot_bgcolor: 'rgb(52, 54, 60)',
      paper_bgcolor: 'rgb(52, 54, 60)',
    };

    var chart = {data: [trace], layout: layout};

    var pngOptions = {format: 'png', width: 1000, height: 500};

    plotly.getImage(chart, pngOptions, function (err, imageData) {
        if (err) throw err
        var pngStream = fs.createWriteStream('test.png');
        imageData.pipe(pngStream);
    })
}

function run(){
    generate_plot()
    // proceed with the generated plot which should be in the filesystem
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

I have removed my previous answers, because (as you correctly pointed out) they didn't solve the full problem.

There are two asynchronous tasks that need to complete before we return control outside of the `generate_plot()` function:  retrieving data from Plotly, and writing that content to disk.

The example below calls `generate_plot()`, and then (as a test to validate whether the file is really on disk) it immediately copies `test.png` to `test2.png`.  Because this results in both files being the same size, this demonstrates that the `fs.copyFileSync` is not running until the `test.png` file is fully on disk.

I did change some of your variable names slightly, but this should work now.

For waiting for the file stream to finish, I reference this question:  [event associated with fs.createWriteStream in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156243/event-associated-with-fs-createwritestream-in-node-js)

```
function generate_plot() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var trace = {
      type: 'bar',
      x: ['Mario', 'Luigi', 'Bowser'],
      y: [50000, 10000, 2000],
      marker: { color: ["red", "green", "darkblue"] },
    };

    var layout = {
      plot_bgcolor: 'rgb(52, 54, 60)',
      paper_bgcolor: 'rgb(52, 54, 60)',
    };

    var chart = { data: [trace], layout: layout };

    var pngOptions = { format: 'png', width: 1000, height: 500 };

    plotly.getImage(chart, pngOptions, (err, imageStream) => {
      if ( err ) return reject(err);
      var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream('test.png');
      imageStream.pipe(fileStream);
      fileStream.on('error', reject);
      fileStream.on('finish', resolve);
    });
  });
}

function run() {
  generate_plot()
    .then(() => {
      fs.copyFileSync('test.png', 'test2.png');
      console.log('done');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for the help and the response, it was the idea I was searching for... The small problem which occured is, that the image is not quite ready yet when trying to access it in `run()`. I have put an extra `setTimeout()` after calling `imageData.pipe()` which is working, but not really the most elegant way of doing it, I suppose. Do you know any better way of doing it? Because if I use your solution and then proceed with the plot, the image is still loading and not quite set-up yet

Comment: My apologies, there's two asynchronous tasks that need to be done; retrieving the content from Plotly, and writing that content to disk.  The above solution only fixes the first one.  I'll revise the answer to show how to wait for the file to be written.

Comment: That does indeed work as intended, thank you! So infact, the 'test2.png' is only a temporary file to synchronize the process and is not really needed afterwards if I understood it right?

Comment: Yes, `test2.png` is only a test to validate that `test.png` is fully on disk at the time that the `fs.copyFileSync` function is run.  If the contents of the two files are the same (which they are, for me), then we have successfully delayed the next command after `generate_plot()` from executing until the `test.png` is fully on disk.  Put another way, you can remove that `fs.copyFileSync` command, and replace it with what you want to do with `test.png` instead.