# PDF download fails using PDFMake in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, pdfmake

I added to my NodeJS API an endpoint to be able to generate and download a PDF using the library PDFMake. I'm able to generate and upload the PDF on the server-side but on browser site, the PDF is downloaded and failed with 0 KBytes on it and I stack trying to find a solution for it. 
I understood that the file is downloaded before the `writeStream` finish to write it but adding an extra function as like:

```
pdf.on("finish", async () => {
            res.download(pdf);
            res.send("PDF generated");
        });
```

This didn't help but added an extra error of:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: undefined
```

I have no idea how to solve this and hope for help. Most probably is something I'm missing.

The code responsible for the functionalities are:
Router

```
router.get("/pdf/all", async (req, res) => {
    const movies = await movie.getMovies();
    try {
        const pdf = await generatePdf(movies, "all");
        pdf.on("finish", async () => {
            res.download(pdf);
            res.send("PDF generated");
        });
    } catch (err) {
        // Errors
        res.status(err.status).json({ message: err.message });
        throw new Error(error.message);
    }
});
```

generatePdf

```
const generatePdf = (movies, name) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            let fonts = {
                Roboto: {
                    normal: "Helvetica",
                    bold: "Helvetica-Bold",
                    italics: "Helvetica-Oblique",
                    bolditalics: "Helvetica-BoldOblique"
                }
            };
            let printer = new pdfMaker(fonts);
            const pdfTemplate = template(movies);
            const pdfStream = printer.createPdfKitDocument(pdfTemplate, {});
            const filePath = path.join(
                __dirname,
                uploads + "/" + pdfDir + `${name}.pdf`
            );
            console.log(filePath);
            pdfStream.pipe(writeStream(filePath));
            pdfStream.end();
            resolve(filePath);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you try the following code for `generatePdf`:

```
const generatePdf = (movies, name) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            let fonts = {
                Roboto: {
                    normal: "Helvetica",
                    bold: "Helvetica-Bold",
                    italics: "Helvetica-Oblique",
                    bolditalics: "Helvetica-BoldOblique"
                }
            };
            let printer = new pdfMaker(fonts);
            const pdfTemplate = template(movies);
            const pdfStream = printer.createPdfKitDocument(pdfTemplate, {});
            const filePath = path.join(
                __dirname,
                uploads + "/" + pdfDir + `${name}.pdf`
            );
            console.log(filePath);
            let stream = pdfStream.pipe(writeStream(filePath));
            stream.on('finish', function(){
                pdfStream.end();
                resolve(filePath);
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err);
        }
    });
};
```

The code should wait for the `pdfStream.pipe` to finish before finishing the file and `resolving` the `filePath`

Also you cannot use `res.send` after `res.download` as the download sets the response to be the file and you can no longer send another response to the client.