# Node.js: wait for zip file to be generated and send response

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-archiver

I am generating a zip file using the module `archiver`. I want to wait for the zip file to be generated before proceeding further. Below is the relevant part of the code.

```
// create a file to stream archive data to.
const archiver = require('archiver');
const fs =  require('fs');

async function zipcsv(zipPath) {
  let output = fs.createWriteStream(zipPath);
  let archive = archiver('zip', {
    zlib: { level: 9 } // Sets the compression level.
  });
  output.on('close', function() {
   return 'zip generating complete';
  });
  archive.pipe(output);
  archive.directory('exports/', false);
  archive.finalize();
}

module.exports.zipcsv = zipcsv;
```

```
zip = require('./zipcsv')
await zip.zipcsv(path);
console.log('futher processing');
```

I see futher processing on the console and the process does not wait for the zip to be generated and continues.

How can I ensure that the zip is generated and then further processing continues.

Thanks.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13157285/905494

Comment: You need to make `zipcsv` into a promise function, just putting `async` in front doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

`archive.finalize()` means that the appending of sub-files in the zip file is completed, but it does not imply that the write streams have completed.
The same has been mentioned in the [README Code pointer](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver/blob/master/README.md?plain=1#L81) of the [node-archiver](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver) library.

There is also an [issue](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver/issues/476) around this but I don't see any action item being taken on this.

There are 2 ways to solve this:

1. Use the callback methods to wait for the write stream to complete.

```
// set a variable to track completion
let isComplete = false; 

// set this variable to true in the callback methods 
output.on('close', function() {
  isComplete = true;
});

archive.finalize();

// after finalize() wait till isComplete is not set to true
while (!isComplete) {
  console.log("waiting...");
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 100);
  });
}
```

2. You can use [adm-zip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adm-zip) which allows you to deal with zip files directly on disk or in memory buffers. It's also simpler to use compared to [node-archiver](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver) library.

[Sample usage](https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip):

```
// creating archives
var zip = new AdmZip();

// add file directly
var content = "inner content of the file";
zip.addFile("test.txt", Buffer.from(content, "utf8"), "entry comment goes here");
// add local file
zip.addLocalFile("/home/me/some_picture.png");
// get everything as a buffer
var willSendthis = zip.toBuffer();
// or write everything to disk
zip.writeZip(/*target file name*/ "/home/me/files.zip");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) Function inside your async function.
Then use resolve and reject instead of return.

Comment: I did use resolve / reject but the process just hangs and does not complete

Comment: Did you tried it with a Promise Function with resolve/reject and zip.zipcsv(path).then(console.log);